# How to use the require function in solidity?

Tags: python, node.js, json, solidity

Not sure what is going on. Am I using require wrong? I am using pragma 0.8.10.

Here is my transfer function in my contract.

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns(bool success) {
        //Transfer Exception if account doesnt have enough
        //Transfer Event
        //Return a Boolean
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value,"revert");
    }
}
```

And Here is My Test Function

```
it('transfers token ownership', function() {
        return DappToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
            tokenInstance = instance;
            return tokenInstance.transfer.call(accounts[1], 99999999999999);
        }).then(assert.fail).catch(function(error){
            assert(error.message.indexOf('revert') >= 0, 'error message must contain revert')
        })
    });
```

I am not sure why this test is not passing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `require` does not return a `bool`. It will raise an error if its condition does not evaluate to true, otherwise it does nothing.

Comment: so return string 'revert' instead?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the testing syntax. What are you trying to test/return?